# Конвертер функции с возвращаемым типом T в функцию с возвращаемым типом string

Tags: c++, c++11

Пытался написать функцию, которая делает то, что указано в заголовке:

```
template<class T>
function<string(int)> conv(function<T(int)> f) {
    return [&](int x) -> string {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << f(x);
        return ss.str();
    };
}
```

[ideone](http://ideone.com/9tkXro)

clang выдает такую ошибку:

```
prog.cpp:28:3: error: no matching function for call to 'conv'
                conv(f1),
                ^~~~
prog.cpp:17:23: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (int)>' against 'int (*)(int)'
function<string(int)> conv(function<T(int)> f) {
```

Или такое только макросами делается?

Полный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int f1(int x) {
}

string f2(int x) {
}

long long f3(int x) {
}

template<class T>
function<string(int)> conv(function<T(int)> f) {
    return [&](int x) -> string {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << f(x);
        return ss.str();
    };
}

int main() {

    vector<function<string(int)>> funcs = {
        conv(f1),
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас аргумент `conv` не преобразуется автоматически в `std::function`, вам надо или поменять саму функцию:

```
template<class T>
function<string(int)> conv(T(*f)(int)) { //меняем сигнатуру
    return [f](int x) -> string { // завхватываем f по значению
        stringstream ss;
        ss << f(x);
        return ss.str();
    };
}
```

или заворачивать аргумент функции в `std::function`:

```
vector<function<string(int)>> funcs = {
    conv(std::function<int(int)>(f1)),
};
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/cOnetE)

Comment: Ну это же уже будет run-time. А макросы и шаблоны все таки в compile-time получаться

Comment: @AndrioSkur так то да, но хотелось бы чтобы подтянулись спецы по C++ и пояснили почему так. Возможно я неправильно что-то где-то использую и другим объясняю :) Возможно тут где-то высплывает UB или еще какая гадость, о которой я и не подозреваю.

Comment: Я так понял, что лямбда функция создается в compile-time, а в run-time просто ссылка на неё возвращается.

Comment: @pank а черт его знает, все равно объяснить, что тут за баг, я не могу. То что я написал в конце это совсем магия какая-то, надеюсь у вас ничего такого не случится, если вы вдруг рискнете использовать мой код, но просто чтоб вы знали что тут есть нечто такое, что ломает все.

Comment: @Flowneee если поменять местами `funcs[3](13)` и `funcs[2](12)`: http://ideone.com/TH0Poz, то тоже не падает :)

Comment: @pank да там вообще как-то ОЧЕНЬ странно. У меня получилось уронить и на строке с первым `cout`, я совсем не знаю что это такое.

Comment: «Что это вообще такое» — обычное UB, Вы же используете ссылку на объект, который уже не существует, так что всё закономерно. Кстати, не обязательно вызывать `conv` с полной записью `function`, достаточно явно указать аргумент шаблона, например: `conv<int>(...)`

Comment: И ещё: создание `std::function` внутри лямбды совершенно не нужный шаг, вызывайте просто функцию по указателю и всё.

Comment: @ixSci все, ясно, спасибо. По последнему комментарию сейчас поправлю.